# Save embedded word document from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the below code for exporting an embedded Word document in a Excel Sheet to the workbook's path:

```
Private Sub Export()

Dim sh As Shape
Dim objWord As Object 'Word.Document
Dim objOLE As OLEObject

    Set sh = Sheet1.Shapes("Object 1")

    sh.OLEFormat.Activate

    Set objOLE = sh.OLEFormat.Object

    Set objWord = objOLE.Object

    objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyTemplate.docx", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatDocumentDefault

End Sub
```

The above code is working fine, but I was looking to add that the Word Applications starts as invisible and that it exits MS Word at the end of the code. I have tried using `objWord.Visible = False` and `objWord.Quit` but when I add these lines I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

Please advise.

Comment: `objWord` is the document: if you want to get a reference to the Word instance then maybe try `objWord.Application`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this

```
objWord.Application.Visible = False
```

and this

```
objWord.Application.Quit
```

Comment: That did it. Totally forgot about adding the `.Application` part. Thanks